# How can I call the webapi controller method from the different view page in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I call the webapi controller method from a different view page in mvc4?

This is my Controller:

**/api/GetEmployee/1**

```
    public EmployeeVM GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new WorkerDBContext())
        {
            var model = db.Employee.Find(id);
            if (model != null)
            {
                return model;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is your WebApi controller name `GetEmployee`? or is that the method name? if so, then what's the controller name?

Comment: GetEmployee name is my methode name my web api controller name is userprofile so the problem is..I have lots of methode for post,put,delet like in this some methodes i can able to call using ajax in a different view  but some methode i can't..please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your data access code to another class (repository pattern would be a good fit) and just call that method from both Controllers.

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
     private readonly WorkerDBContext _workerDbContext = new WorkerDBContext();
     public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
     {
          var model = _workerDbContext.Employee.Find(id);
          return model;
     }
}
```

Then from your Controllers:

```
private readonly EmployeeRepository _employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();

public EmployeeVM GetEmployee(int id)
{
      var employee = _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(id);
      var viewModel = new EmployeeVM { Name = employeeName, ... };
      return viewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that you have multiple `Get` , `Put`, `Post`, etc. in the same controller and WebApi (or REST) services for that matter work based on the action type of the request. Either way the default route in WebApi does not have an action, so make this change to your route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouterParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then create a link/call to your api controllers this way:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ActionRoute", new {httproute= "", controller = "controller", action = "action"});
```